# Capture audio from android app

Tags: android

I am trying to capture audio from the app.

I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.RESULT_UPLOAD_AUDIO);
```

As soon as I click the capture audio button, I am returned back to the app in onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data), where data is null.

It works fine for video:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent,Constants.RESULT_UPLOAD_VIDEO);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar problem. I did the following as a work around and it works perfectly fine:

[Invoking audio recorder and getting the resulting file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746979/invoking-audio-recorder-and-getting-the-resulting-file)

Hope this helps.